# Как отделить один блок в CSS, от другого

Tags: css, html5

При верстке сайта я разделил его на три блока: `<header>`, `<main>`, `<footer>`. Проблема в том что блок `<main>` прилипает к `<header>`. Верстку веду по шаблону из Figma. То есть блок `<main>` соеденяется с `<header>`
в один блок. Если открыть консоль и посмотреть на `margin-top`, то можно увидеть отступы для двух блоков. Хотя отступ должен быть только для `<main>` Может стоит попробовать изменить позиционирование? Заранее благодарен. Я новичок, поэтому не судите строго.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(png/background1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  font-family: Noto Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  max-height: 47px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #26529C;
}

.logo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

main {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="svg/logo.svg">
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="block1">
      <img src="svg/block1.svg" class="block1_rectangle">
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>

  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Составьте [mcve] без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: Можно скриншот как "прилипает"?

Comment: @Иван, Вас смущает то, что header не прилипает к верху экрана? Или я неправильно понял вопрос? Скиньте скрин, как прилипает

Comment: _«`<main>` прилипает к `<header>`»_ - пример в вопросе показывает что все в порядке, проблему он не воспрозводит: https://imgur.com/JZUxXtX

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того чтобы присваивать `.logo {margin-top: 10px}`, задай внутренний отступ для `header` или `.logo`, если я правильно понял вопрос. `header {padding-top: 10px}` или `.logo {padding-top: 10px}`

Answer (score 0):

У элементов страницы есть свои базовые стили. Чтобы их обнулить, надо вначале написать: *{margin:0; padding:0}.